# Fixed menu overlaps div under it

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed menu, after it I have a div which have fixed background-image. Problem is that menu overlap second image (so 100 px of image located under menu).

> Example Link: http://codepen.io/gorez16rus/pen/GZjgNB

Image link: http://www.mygracefalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/upcoming-events_std_t-e1374861489324.jpg

Menu:

```
.home-wrap header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Div:

```
.event-box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 520px;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('http://www.mygracefalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/upcoming-events_std_t-e1374861489324.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this, is to change the background-position of the image:

```
background-position: center 100px;
```

[Modified version of your code on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWpYoO)

Comment: No, this way you move image inside of a div, but i need to move div from under the menu. Size of div is 520px size of menu is 100px, so total should be 520 + 100 = 620, but on the screen only 520px

Comment: Then you also have to add `padding-top: 100px` to your `.home-section` (if your content is inside the home-section).